# How to Enable Directory Indexing on GitHub Pages

Tags: git, github, indexing, server

I need to display directory contents on GH Pages.

Would prefer

1. Automatically, without index.html
2. A tool or library for automatically generating the index.html
3. Any other method

So, if I have a FS in my GH Pages repository:

`http://github.com/[username]/[username].github.io/` :

```
script/
- app/
  - core/
    - init.js
- lib/
  - Element.animate.js
  - Object.overlay.js
- mod/
  - anim/
    - global/
      - carousel/
        - carousel.js
      - global.js
- ext/
  - cfgs.js
index.html
```

I would want each directory URL to index as usual, like so.

`http://[username].github.io/script/` :

```
- app/
- lib/
- mod/
- ext/
```

`http://[username].github.io/script/mod/anim/global/` :

```
- carousel/
- global.js
```

The only thing I can think of is preference #2, write or find a script to automatically generate the index.html from the GitHub Repo page or the local Repo on my FS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I also wanted to do this.  I tried uploading an `.htaccess` file with contents `Options +Indexes` to the relevant directory, but that did not work.

So, I used your option #2, writing a tiny Python script to generate an index file for the directory.

```py
""" Build index from directory listing

make_index.py </path/to/directory> [--header <header text>]
"""

INDEX_TEMPLATE = r"""
<html>
<body>
<h2>${header}</h2>
<p>
% for name in names:
    <li><a href="${name}">${name}</a></li>
% endfor
</p>
</body>
</html>
"""

EXCLUDED = ['index.html']

import os
import argparse

# May need to do "pip install mako"
from mako.template import Template


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("directory")
    parser.add_argument("--header")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    fnames = [fname for fname in sorted(os.listdir(args.directory))
              if fname not in EXCLUDED]
    header = (args.header if args.header else os.path.basename(args.directory))
    print(Template(INDEX_TEMPLATE).render(names=fnames, header=header))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The idea is to create locally a list with the script, then copy the html to a html file and upload it to github. So for me the next step is to output the list to a html file and not print it to the terminal.

Comment: Do you have a demo of this?

Answer (score 37):

If you want a dynamic index that doesn't require any updating the only method I've found is by generating it client side with the [github contents api](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/).

Here is a simple example that creates links to files in the top level directory of your project. If you want to support subdirectories using this method you would have to recursively request the contents of each folder.

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      (async () => {
        const response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/contents/');
        const data = await response.json();
        let htmlString = '<ul>';
        
        for (let file of data) {
          htmlString += `<li><a href="${file.path}">${file.name}</a></li>`;
        }

        htmlString += '</ul>';
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = htmlString;
      })()
    </script>
  <body>
</html>
```

[Here's an example](https://www.timetler.com/recipes/) where I used this to create a simple directory for a flat repo I have.

Comment: This might be a solution I am looking for. Do you know if this API support multi level (nested) folders.

Comment: That is a great solution. I just created myself an image gallery index from this with a little bit uhtml magic. https://geolytix.github.io/MapIcons/

Comment: [This](https://docs.github.com/v3/repos/contents/) is the new link to the docs! The suggested edit queue is full, thats why I put it here.

Comment: very useful thank you. small note that obvious for most but it took me few attempts to get it. remove the colon : when adding your username and repo name. eg `https://api.github.com/repos/myrepo/repo1/contents/` not `https://api.github.com/repos/:myrepo/:repo1/contents/`

Answer (score 7):

Better is this way which will go into subdirectory and make index files for them as well

```
""" Build index from directory listing

make_index.py </path/to/directory> [--header <header text>]
"""
from __future__ import print_function
import os.path, time

INDEX_TEMPLATE = r"""

<html>
<head>
<title>${header}</title>
<meta name="description" content="${header}"/>

</head>
<body>
    <h2>Index of ${header}</h2>
    <p>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th valign="top"><img src="${ROOTDIR}images/blank.gif"
                    alt="[ICO]"></th>
                <th><a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a></th>
                <th><a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a></th>
                <th><a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a></th>
                <th><a href="?C=D;O=A">Description</a></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="5"><hr></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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 "
                    alt="[PARENTDIR]"></td>
                <td><a href="../">Parent Directory</a></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="right">-</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="5"><hr></th>
            </tr>

            % for name in dirnames:
            <tr>
                <td valign="top"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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 "
                    alt="[DIR]"></td>
                <td><a href="${name}">${name}</a></td>
                <td align="right">${time}</td>
                <td align="right">-</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            % endfor
            % for name in filenames:
            <tr>
                <td valign="top"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAIAAACQkWg2AAAABnRSTlMAAAAAAABupgeRAAABHUlEQVR42o2RMW7DIBiF3498iHRJD5JKHurL+CRVBp+i2T16tTynF2gO0KSb5ZrBBl4HHDBuK/WXACH4eO9/CAAAbdvijzLGNE1TVZXfZuHg6XCAQESAZXbOKaXO57eiKG6ft9PrKQIkCQqFoIiQFBGlFIB5nvM8t9aOX2Nd18oDzjnPgCDpn/BH4zh2XZdlWVmWiUK4IgCBoFMUz9eP6zRN75cLgEQhcmTQIbl72O0f9865qLAAsURAAgKBJKEtgLXWvyjLuFsThCSstb8rBCaAQhDYWgIZ7myM+TUBjDHrHlZcbMYYk34cN0YSLcgS+wL0fe9TXDMbY33fR2AYBvyQ8L0Gk8MwREBrTfKe4TpTzwhArXWi8HI84h/1DfwI5mhxJamFAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC "
                    alt="[DIR]"></td>
                <td><a href="${name}">${name}</a></td>
                <td align="right">${time}</td>
                <td align="right">-</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            % endfor
            </p>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
"""

EXCLUDED = ['index.html']

import os
import argparse

# May need to do "pip install mako"
from mako.template import Template

def fun(dir,rootdir):
    print('Processing: '+dir)
    filenames = [fname for fname in sorted(os.listdir(dir))
              if fname not in EXCLUDED and os.path.isfile(dir+fname)]
    dirnames = [fname for fname in sorted(os.listdir(dir))
            if fname not in EXCLUDED  ]
    dirnames = [fname for fname in dirnames if fname not in filenames]
#    header = os.path.basename(dir)
    f = open(dir+'/index.html','w')
    print(Template(INDEX_TEMPLATE).render(dirnames=dirnames,filenames=filenames, header=dir,ROOTDIR=rootdir,time=time.ctime(os.path.getctime(dir))),file=f)
    f.close()
    for subdir in dirnames:
        try:
            fun(dir+subdir+"/",rootdir+'../')
        except:
            pass

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("directory")
    parser.add_argument("--header")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    fun(args.directory+'/','../')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a program for this.

[image]

See [apindex](https://github.com/libthinkpad/apindex).

Answer (score 1):

If your purpose is just to display the directory contents and you do not care much about how the overall page with the contents looks like, why not just giving to the consumers a link to the underlying repository folder?

In your case it would be something like
[https://github.io/[Repo](https://github.io/%5BRepo) name]/tree/master/[Folder name]

It will display a regular github files list view with a possibility to view and download each of them.

Comment: Did you try it? It gives error 404 for me.

Comment: I tried it and works. The repo is public, so you can open it in GitHub, navigate to the folder and then copy the URL and give it to anyone, and it'll work. ... Of course, this is different from having a website on GitHub pages, but for some scenarios it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

2023 update: With Github actions you can do the site build remotely. https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-pages-directory-listing which does just that. The author initially maintained a fork of @Gala's apindex, but later switched to this new code base.