# How to make a root page that shows all the files and folder in root dir?

Tags: html, apache, web-deployment, web-hosting

This seems weird but I am trying to make the apache root page from scratch where it shows all the files and folders and you can go into the folders etc. I am not even sure where to start. The reason I want this is that I am hosting on Github Pages.

Comment: Are you trying to configure apache to show directory list pages, or are you trying to simulate the look-and-feel of apache's default list pages?  If the latter, the HTML is just a `<h1>` with the folder name, followed by an unordered list of links.

Comment: i am just trying to simulate it, since i can run apache off github

Comment: but i am not able to figure out how to get the links to the subfolder to work

Comment: If it's the HTML you're having trouble with, `<a href="subfolder/">subfolder link</a>`.   If it's that you want GitHub to generate the list pages for you based on the folder contents, I don't think that's possible, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048654/how-to-enable-directory-indexing-on-github-pages) has some answers that may be helpful.